# Wait until Excel RefreshAll (Ctrl+Alt+F5) finishes - VBA

Tags: vba, excel, mutex, race-condition

I am running into a race condition issue where I have two QueryTables, each is hooked with its own AfterRefresh event. Each AfterRefresh event does some copy'n'pasting as well as doing some calculations.

Now, when the user click Refresh All `(Ctrl+Alt+F5)` in Excel, I would love to have each AfterRefresh handler to execute, but ONLY after all QueryTable refreshes are entirely completed.

I did a search on StackOverFlow, and [someone suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22088630/336470)

```
Activeworkbook.RefreshAll
DoEvents
```

However, that's assuming that we are programmatically triggering the RereshAll. In my case, Refresh All is done by the built-in Refresh All `(Ctrl+Alt+F5)` button within Excel. Thus, I don't see where I can insert `DoEvents` in my case (unless I create my own Refresh All button, but I would like to avoid doing so).

I tried to search for "Excel VBA mutex", but I did not find anything in particular. So how do I make sure that all the refreshes are done, before each AfterRefresh handler takes place?

Thanks for reading!

Update: To help out with debugging.. here are my VBA codes.

I have a module named `AutoOpen`

```
Dim S As New DataCopy
Dim U As New DataCopy

Sub Auto_Open()
    Set S.qt = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).QueryTables(2)
    S.myWorkbookName = ThisWorkbook.Name
    S.sWorksheetProcessName = "ProcessS"
    S.sWorksheetDataColumnStart = 1
    S.sWorksheetDataColumnEnd = 5
    Set U.qt = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).QueryTables(1)
    U.myWorkbookName = ThisWorkbook.Name
    U.sWorksheetProcessName = "ProcessU"
    U.sWorksheetDataColumnStart = 6
    U.sWorksheetDataColumnEnd = 10
End Sub
```

I also have a Class module named `DataCopy`

```
Public WithEvents qt As QueryTable
Public myWorkbookName As String
Public sWorksheetProcessName As String
Public sWorksheetDataColumnStart As Integer
Public sWorksheetDataColumnEnd As Integer

Private Sub qt_AfterRefresh(ByVal Success As Boolean)
    DataCopier
End Sub

Private Sub DataCopier()
    'Debug.Print sWorksheetProcessName & "," & Application.CalculationState
    Dim LastNRows As Integer
    Dim sWorksheetDataName As String

    ' How many rows to copy
    LastNRows = 297
    sWorksheetDataName = "Data"

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    ' Clear content in process tab
    With Workbooks(myWorkbookName).Worksheets(sWorksheetProcessName)
        .Range(.Cells(4, 1), .Cells(.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row, 6)).ClearContents
    End With

    ' Copy to process Tab
    With Workbooks(myWorkbookName).Worksheets(sWorksheetDataName)
        LastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        FirstRow = LastRow - LastNRows
        If FirstRow < 2 Then
            FirstRow = 2
        End If
        .Range(.Cells(FirstRow, sWorksheetDataColumnStart), .Cells(LastRow, sWorksheetDataColumnEnd)).Copy _
             Destination:=Workbooks(myWorkbookName).Worksheets(sWorksheetProcessName).Range("A4")
    End With

    Debug.Print (sWorksheetProcessName & "," & sWorksheetDataColumnStart & "," & sWorksheetDataColumnEnd)

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Because of the race condition, only one AfterRefresh handler succeeds in copy'n'pasting.. the other one doesn't work until I click Refresh All button `(Ctrl+Alt+F5)` again.

Comment: Perhaps each `AfterRefresh` event handler can end with `Activeworkbook.RefreshAll` followed by `DoEvents`, perhaps with some toggling Boolean public variables to prevent echoing events.

Comment: @JohnColeman, but the user already clicked the built-in Refresh All button, so if I add `Activeworkbook.RefreshAll` to each `AfterRefresh` doesn't that mean it is essentially refreshing twice?
Actually, on second thought, since it is within `AfterRefresh`, it would trigger infinite loop in refresh? Because `AfterRefresh` triggers yet another refresh, which triggers `AfterRefresh` again

Comment: I see the problem a little more clearly now. Perhaps include a timer loop at the beginning of each of the event handlers with a `DoEvents` in the body of the loop. Each of the event handler can pause for a few seconds while they allow the refresh to finish. It might even be as simple as including a `DoEvents` at the beginning of each of the handlers. You are going to need some sort of kludge because Excel isn't really designed for multithreading. Also -- I don't remember now what it was, by I once encountered a situation that required two `DoEvents` in a row. As an experiment start both with 2

Comment: @JohnColeman Thanks. I will try it out. and report back. The problem with race condition is that the repro is not always consistent. Fortunately, it is 9 out of 10 times reproducible.

Comment: @JohnColeman `DoEvents` appears to do the trick so far. I simply inserted inside `qt_AfterRefresh`
Feel free to submit that as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a `DoEvents` works after the explicit VBA trigger `Activeworkbook.RefreshAll` then a `DoEvents` *before* the code that you want to run in the event handlers should cover the case when the refresh is triggered by `Ctrl+Alt+F5`. Thus, begin each event handler with the line `DoEvents`.

Comment: Please explain your solution further. I am afraid I do not understand.

Answer (score 0):

change the queries to not allow background refresh, and they will not relinquish control until refreshed

[image: Location of Background refresh]

Comment: Is this something that can be done from the Connection property UI? or is this only done in VBA? Because if it is in code, I don't know if I need to invest in logic to check if it is already set to False or not.

DoEvents appear to do the trick so far though, but I will try yours out too.

Comment: added picture of where to find the background refresh option

Comment: Thanks Sean. I see why you have that option whereas I don't because my external sources are simply two continuously updating CSV files not SQL connection.